# How to implement a location specific convolutional filters in Tensorflow or Pytorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I want to implement a convolutional layer, with a different convolutional filter for each output location. Specifically, think of the case when the output is of 16*16*128 (W * H * C). Instead of having a 3*3*128 filter we have 16*16 filters; each with size 3*3*128. This would lead to huge amount of parameters, but it can the case be that each of the 3*3*128 filter may be the same except scaled by a different constant, and the constants can be learned through a side network. In this way the number of parameters won't be too much.

The similar idea is briefly in [Dynamic Filter Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.09673), but I cannot find an implementation of location specific filters. My question is, if we want a location specific convolutional filter how do I implement it in Tensorflow or Pytorch? Do I need to write my own operation or there is some smart way to use the functions provided? If I have to write an OP is there any trick that can easily achieve this idea? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "each of the 3*3*128 filter may be the same except scaled by a different constant" is equivalent to using a normal convolution (with a 3*3*128 filter the same at every location) followed by scaling the output at each location by a learned factor

Comment: @myrtlecat yes I see, but that is just a simple case motivation. For a more interesting example, still a 3*3*128 filter, but at each location, this filter is elementwise multiplied by a location-specific 3*3 matrix across the channels. This would not increase the parameter by much.

Answer (score 3):

A convolution, by definition, is **not** location specific - this is what makes it a convolution. If you wish to generalize convolution, bear in mind that eventually a convolution is a special case of a simple linear operation. Therefore, you can implement your "location specific" convolution as a fully-connected layer (`nn.Linear`) with a very specific sparse weights.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why convolutions are more efficient than fully connected layers is *beacause* they are translation invariant. If you wish to have convolutions which are dependent on location you would need to add two extra parameters to the convolution i.e. having N+2 input channels where x, y coord are the values of the two additonal channels (as in e.g. [CoordConv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03247), or [Location Biased Convolutions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.02927.pdf)).